# Connect to a MySQL DB with JSP through another class

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, exception, servlets

Can I connect to a MySQL DB with JSP through another class?

Here is my my own suggestion:

```
...<body>

<h3>The User List</h3>
<br>
<%
// JSP/Java kode
UsersDAPInterface users = new UserDAPClass(); // This java class contains mysql connection etc.
%>
</body>...
```

When I do this, I get a lot of errors and exceptions, including `ClassNotFound`, `NullPointer` etc.

I also got this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Which should mean that it doesn't have the mysql driver.. But I have imported the mysql driver so I don't know if it should be imported in a different way than usually. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: try putting <%@ page import="packageName.UserDAPClass"%> at the top your page.

Comment: Note:  A `<br>` after an `</h3>` is entirely redundant.  Headers are block level elements typically with a significant bottom padding.

Comment: Ismet: I already have that.. eclipse did it for me. It didn't work :(

Comment: can you add a breakpoint into UserDAPClass and paste the code part the the exception is thrown?

Comment: This is the code where the exception is thrown: Class.forName(dbdriver);
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbAdress, dbUsername, dbpassWord); Just a simple connection ..

Comment: are you using eclipse just for war creation and once war is created you are deploying this war to the server  yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that this jar file in present in **WEB-INF/lib** folder of your application, as long as its present there, this issue should not come.

Comment: The jar file (mysql connector) places itself in the "referenced library", even when I try to put it in the WEB-INF folder like u say

Comment: Well I be damned, it worked :) I tried putting the jar file i the folder you told me, manually instead. Thanks for the short an sweet solution

Comment: its good that it worked :), but a good practice, avoid or infact never have scriptlet in your jsp. I am not sure what are your requirement that made you do DB operation in jsp. ideally this should have been done by servlet by getcall or an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

```
<jsp:useBean/> use this action to load any class to jsp. This is best practice.      

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

This exceptions occurs due to your MySQL Connector Driver is not laoded. Use an IDE to load the driver. Manually check whether the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is founded by writing it on Java class.

Comment: How do I do that ? .. I already imported with eclipse like with a normal java application, but it's not working with this Dynamc Web Project. it's located in a referenced library.. Should it be placed somewhere else or imported differently?

Answer (score 0):

Download lib file from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) and put it in your lib folder of your application. Have no idea what IDE are you using, but on Netbeans, take following steps:

1. Right click on your project
2. Select properties
3. In the category panel, select Libraries
4. Add jar folder just downloaded from Maven
5. You are ready.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jdbc driver class in your webapp library.